# 90s(?) cartoon movie: female servant enters the castle's forbidden room when the Lord is away, he tries to kill her for it

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

There was a dark castle I think, that is no one should come in! And there was a servant or someone like this in it, who served a lord vampire (or maybe not a vampire!).

There was a big room in this castle that the lord vampire wouldn't let anyone enter, and that room had a key that the Lord gave to the girl on a white bandana, saying to the girl, "Take care of the castle till I'm back".

One day the curious girl after her lord left, took the key and tried to open the door -- and after that, blood splashed out of the keyhole and the girl discovered a secret about her lord and castle.

I don't remember exactly what happened next, but after this, the Lord realized the girl used the key and try to kill her? I think, somehow, the castle caught on fire and the girl tried to escape from the lord and fire, and at last the girl jumped into the river or sea or something? and watched the burning castle!

I think the art style looked like the "Castlevania* games or something like that. I've seen this animation when I was 7 or 8 and now I am 22, so it should be created in the 1990s (or before 2003 anyway).

Comment: Your story sounds somewhat like "Bluebeard" and how the girl he chose as a bride, decided to use the key and enter the room despite him telling her not to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this version of [Bluebeard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluebeard) from the [*Grimm's Fairy Tale Classics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_Fairy_Tale_Classics) anime:

Bloody key is at 5:28. Castle catching fire at 8:18

[image: Bloody key] [image: Burning castle]

The clip shows up when I did a search for *cartoon vampire bluebeard*